# Ubuntu 16.04 app installations outside of software center and can be used via terminal or .deb

Tags: java, software-center, dell, steam, vnc

I have a dell Optiplex 755 usff and I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it and I want to install apps on it but outside of the Ubuntu software center. How can I do this and not run into any errors? Also what apps are recommended for a start to ubuntu? I would like java, flash, VNC, Steam, Utilities, and customization apps? (I'm just asking here how can I install applications on Ubuntu without any pre-installed applications and not run into any errors)

Comment: I can do it, but I have years of training and experience with Linux. Do you? If not, you are on an unwise path toward great frustration. If you are a beginner, then *try to use Ubuntu the way it is meant to be used*.  Learn to ride the bicycle without training wheels before you enter your first race.

Comment: That depends on the specific application. Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) for each one as questions about multiple unrelated topics are too broad to answer within the scope of this site. Better yet, search for “install [application name]” on Ask Ubuntu, sort by votes and you should find installation procedure for the most popular applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed broad but simply put you install apps outside Ubuntu Software Center by using `.deb` file and installing them from the commandline or terminal. The steps are simply:

1. Download the file say: `myapp.deb`
2. Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
3. Type: `sudo dpkg -i myapp.deb`
4. Get any dependency errors from `step 3`, then do:

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Repeat step 3

Please spend some time reading about Ubuntu in general so you will understand the basics.

Comment: `gdebi` is a great alternative to using `dpkg`. No `install -f` yadayada simply `sudo gdebi package.deb`.

Comment: At times the yadayada is good for the soul :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can install apps without using the software center. It does require the use of a terminal, however.

The easiest way if from `apt`

> apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package
>   management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables
>   some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to
>   more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

You can use it like:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

and it will install vlc player for you.

The other method is obtaining the `.deb` files, or download links. To download a `deb` file, get the URL, and

```
sudo wget urltodebfile
```

and then, install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i debfile.deb
```

followed by

```
sudo apt install -f
```

to fix any missing dependencies.

If you're interested:

> dpkg  is  a  tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian packages.
>   The primary and more user-friendly front-end for dpkg  is  aptitude(1).
>   dpkg  itself  is controlled entirely via command line parameters, which
>   consist of exactly one action and zero or  more  options.  The  action-
>   parameter tells dpkg what to do and options control the behavior of the
>   action in some way.

Note: The quotes are from the man pages

Comment: There's one app but I need to know also how to uninstall apps as well as when I uninstall it. It gets rid of everything that it came with the first time I execute it. What other apps can you recommend for me to use on ubuntu 16.04?